# How can i persist token info without localStorage? React + Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to persist token info in whole application but the only way i know is using localStorage (which most people said it's the worst way to security).

What can i do to avoid use localStorage or maybe turn this more secure

Action.js

```
export const setarToken = (token, status) => {
  return {
    type: SETAR_TOKEN,
    token: token,
    result: status
  }
}

export const loginUsuario = (email, senha) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    API.get('usuario/autorizar?email=' + email + '&senha='  + senha)
    .then((res) =>{
      dispatch(setarToken(res.data.token, 'success'))
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      throw(error);
    })
  }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
case SETAR_TOKEN:
            localStorage.setItem('API_TOKEN', action.token)
            return null
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way is Use ReduxPersist package....[refer here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Answer (score 0):

Found some good tips here: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens

So you are correct, persisting in local is a bad idea. Either way up if cookies are a viable option or just persist in memory with a new token request with each request.